# Graphing data frame segments with invalidateLater

Tags: r, statistics, shiny

I currently have a graph in my shiny graph that is from a data frame.  I want to break that data frame into 10 parts so I can create a progression (show the graph being built essentially).  I'm having trouble getting this to work.

I figured I'd have to use an invalidateLater and a reactive variable.  So that's what I tried however can't seem to get it to work.

## UI.R

```
##UI.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("NBA Simulation","NBA Simulation"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(


      helpText("Choose two different NBA teams to simulate a game!"),

      selectInput("team1",
                  label="Team 1:",
                  choices=list("Atlanta Hawks"=1, "Boston Celtics"=2, "Brooklyn Nets"=3, "Charlotte Hornets"=4, "Chicago Bulls"=5, "Cleveland Cavaliers"=6, "Dallas Mavericks"=7, "Denver Nuggets"=8, "Detroit Pistons"=9, "Golden State Warriors"=10, "Houston Rockets"=11, "Indiana Pacers"=12, "LA Clippers"=13, "LA Lakers"=14, "Memphis Grizzlies"=15, "Miami Heat"=16, "Milwaukee Bucks"=17, "Minnesota Timberwolves"=18, "New Orleans Pelicans"=19, "New York Knicks"=20, "OKC Thunder"=21, "Orlando Magic"=22, "Philadelphia 76ers"=23, "Phoenix Suns"=24, "Portland Trailblazers"=25, "Sacramento Kings"=26, "San Antonio Spurs"=27, "Toronto Raptors"=28, "Utah Jazz"=29, "Washington Wizards"=30),
                  selected=1),

      selectInput("team2",
                  label="Team 2:",
                  choices=list("Atlanta Hawks"=1, "Boston Celtics"=2, "Brooklyn Nets"=3, "Charlotte Hornets"=4, "Chicago Bulls"=5, "Cleveland Cavaliers"=6, "Dallas Mavericks"=7, "Denver Nuggets"=8, "Detroit Pistons"=9, "Golden State Warriors"=10, "Houston Rockets"=11, "Indiana Pacers"=12, "LA Clippers"=13, "LA Lakers"=14, "Memphis Grizzlies"=15, "Miami Heat"=16, "Milwaukee Bucks"=17, "Minnesota Timberwolves"=18, "New Orleans Pelicans"=19, "New York Knicks"=20, "OKC Thunder"=21, "Orlando Magic"=22, "Philadelphia 76ers"=23, "Phoenix Suns"=24, "Portland Trailblazers"=25, "Sacramento Kings"=26, "San Antonio Spurs"=27, "Toronto Raptors"=28, "Utah Jazz"=29, "Washington Wizards"=30),
                  selected=2),

      submitButton("Submit")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h1("Final Result"),
      htmlOutput("simLogo1"),
      htmlOutput("simResult"),
      htmlOutput("simLogo2"),
      plotOutput("scrPlot")
    )

)))
```

## server.R

```
##server.R
source("TwoTeamSimulation.R")
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  output$simResult <- renderText({
    team1 <- input$team1
    team2<- input$team2
    simgame(team1,team2)
  })

  output$simLogo1 <- renderText({
    team1 <- input$team1
    sprintf('<img src="%s.jpg" height="150" width="350"/>', team1)
  })

  output$simLogo2 <- renderText({
    team2 <- input$team2
    sprintf('<img src="%s.jpg" height="150" width="350"/>', team2)
  })

  reactPlot<-reactive({
    team1<-input$team1
    team2<-input$team2
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    comsc<-c(team1sp,team2sp) 

    teamid <- c(rep("Team 1", length(team1sp)), rep("Team 2", length(team2sp)))

    scoringprog <- data.frame(pos=rep(1:101, 2), score=comsc, team=teamid)
    scoringprog

    graphsp <- ggplot(data=scoringprog, aes(x=pos, y=comsc, color=team)) +
      geom_line(aes(color=team))+
      geom_point(aes(color=team))+
      xlab("Possesion")+
      ylab("Score")+
      ggtitle("Scoring Progression")+
      scale_color_discrete(name="Team Name", 
                           breaks=c("Team 1", "Team 2"), 
                           labels=c(as.character(team1name), as.character(team2name)))
    graphsp
  })

  output$scrPlot <- renderPlot({
    return(reactPlot())
  })
})
```

I tried creating a for loop and function that used the following data frame extraction:

```
scoringprog <- scoringprog[c(1:10*n,102:111+((10*(n-1))),1:3]
```

However that didn't seem to work either.

Any input is greatly appreciated!